# Win XP connection shared over non-192.168.0.1 LAN

Tags: linux, networking, windows-xp, connection-sharing, usb-modem

I have a ZTE MF823 3G modem connected to Windows XP Professional. It is seen by the system as local area connection with IP 192.168.0.1 and netmask 255.255.255.0.

I'd like to share this connection to another computer, with Lubuntu, over ethernet. Unfortunately WinXP requires the eth interface to which other connection is shared to have IP 192.168.0.1 -- so it requries me to have two different network interfaces working in network with colliding addresses.

Is there any possibility to share a network connection with addresses 192.168.0.0/24 to another network (eg. 192.168.1.0/24) and not the other way around?

Trying another approach I managed to change ZTE modem's IP from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.1 -- there is a simple Linux on it, so I could telnet to it, login as `user: root, pass: zte9x15` and via `ifconfig usb0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0` change the IP, then changed Windows connection config to use 192.168.1.2 and I could share that over 192.168.0.0/24-LAN. **But** after reboot ZTE modem came back to IP 192.168.0.1 and all the sharing stopped working.

I am considering permanently changing modem's local IP, however I do not know how to do that. I did `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and got result:

```
root@9615-cdp:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Wireless interfaces
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wireless_mode managed
        wireless_essid any
        wpa-driver wext
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface atml0 inet dhcp

# Wired or wireless interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
iface usb0 inet static
        address 192.168.7.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.7.0
        gateway 192.168.7.1

# Bluetooth networking
iface bnep0 inet dhcp
```

And `ifconfig -a` gives output as below, so it seems that that the `/etc/network/interfaces` is unrelated and I do not know how to change the network and modem adresses for good. So I'm looking for any solution to share network over differently-adressed-LAN **or** to permanently change ZTE modem's address. Thanks for all advices.

Here's the ifconfig's output:

```
root@9615-cdp:~# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7455537 (7.1 MiB)  TX bytes:1207800 (1.1 MiB)

rmnet1    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          inet6 addr: fe80::9d8b:cf2e:2e42:db5c/64 Scope:Link
          UP RUNNING PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 B)  TX bytes:904 (904.0 B)

rmnet2    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet3    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet4    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet5    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet6    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

rmnet7    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
-00
          [NO FLAGS]  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:4B:50:B7:EF:08
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::364b:50ff:feb7:ef08/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5861280 (5.5 MiB)  TX bytes:15526844 (14.8 MiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Microsoft Support article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230148

It documents how you can change the Internet Connection Sharing service's IP range on Windows XP and Windows 7 in the registry.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, because the article doesn't (despite what is written) apply for Windows XP.

As one can see here, on WinXP it is (probably) impossible to change ICSharing addresses: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-networking/changing-the-default-network-number-on-winxp-ics/ac6ab06e-d854-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

So I still need a different fix.